# Swift and Python HTTP Request "GET"

Tags: swift, httprequest

I am making an app that can upload an image to a python backend server with my friends, and I need a little bit help on the http request, was trying to use Alamofire but somehow it needs backend to revise, but the backend cannot be revised because it is already in used with another Android App.

So here is my question, do I need to set the multipart/form-data, and also would you please read my code and give me some suggestions? I will show both of my sides code,

my front end:

```
func myImageUploadRequest()
    {
        // convert image to data object
        guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image!, 1) else {
            print("Could not get JPEG representation of UIImage")
            return
        }

        // send multipart request
        Alamofire.upload( multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "imagefile", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")},

                          to: "http://123.123.123.123/image",
                          headers: ["Authorization": "Basic xxx"],
                          encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

                            // check the response
                            switch encodingResult {
                            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                                upload.uploadProgress { progress in
                                    // Show progress
                                }
                                upload.responseJSON { response in
                                    // Handle response
                                }
                            case .failure(let encodingError):
                                print(encodingError)
                                // Handle Error
                            }
        })
    }
```

I am still confused about this part, so I now have an image select from gallery, and I use an UIImageJPEGRepresentation to represent the image in a UIImageView area, how can I use that part to send to the server?

The back end is very simple, it is :

```
@app.route("/image", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def image():
    if(request.method == 'GET'):
    return '{ Success }' 

    file = request.files['file']
    img = Image.open(request.files['file'])
    img.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename))
    return classify_image.pic_tensorflow('/home/images/file.jpg')
```

Can anyone give any suggestions?

I have changed the info list for the http.

Here are the error I got from the console

2018-03-13 01:42:54.424642-0500 zechengpart[53957:9552037] TIC Read Status [2:0x60000017ec00]: 1:54
2018-03-13 01:42:55.803615-0500 zechengpart[53957:9552112] [] nw_socket_get_input_frames recvmsg(fd 8, 3734 bytes): [54] Connection reset by peer

Comment: You need to create a Multipart POST request which you can do with Alamofire too. Read here for both approaches with and without Alamofire http://blogs.innovationm.com/alamofire/

Comment: Hi Mukesh, I just tried the link you send me, and I did got something from the server end, but it seems there is still no json response, would you please give me some advise on fix this bugs? I will update the code here.

Comment: as you have used `file` as parameter name at server you have to change it in your request change the line `append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")`

Comment: @Mukesh Thanks for helping, this is what I got back from the server: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/lzc/cse-cui/src/back/Application.py", line 85, in image
    img.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file.filename))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1672, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "wb")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'templates/images/file.jpg'

Comment: @Mukesh any thoughts maybe?